# Linux scsi command queue

Tags: linux, command, queue, depth, scsi

I'm a newbie here at this forum.  I'm currently stuck with a problem.

I'm a beginner to Linux kernel drivers, and currently involved in developing a Linux SCSI device driver for a block mass storage device.  The development platform is on a high-end machine with Fedora 14.  The setup is 1 host to one LU/device.  To make the long story short, the driver is working in the sense that it initializes without problems, it can detect the device and send scsi frames to it, it can read and write to the device, and I can do stable Iometer read and write tests through the driver.  All of that when there is only 1 outstanding command at a time (no queueing).

The problem is, I couldn't get queuing to work.  The upper SCSI layers doesn't send me (LLD) more than one commands to be outstanding unless I `scsi_done()` the first command.  I expect that the upper layer can call `queuecommand()` more than once before I send the commands to the device for processing, then for the device to interrupt me for the response and for `LLD` to close the command with `scsi_done()`.  Without queuing, our speed is very slow.

I've already tweaked values I thought are connected to queuing, like setting .can_queue and `.cmd_per_lun` to my target queue_depth in both `scsi_host` and `scsi_host_template`.  Basically I've played with various values including 1, but to no avail.  I also did disable and enable tagging if this has any effect, but still no change.  So far I don't remember doing much with `scsi_device` in the driver, except in `slave_configure`.  Is there anything I'm missing and can still do in driver level?  I can't believe Linux would have no support for command queuing.  I'm missing something here.

Comment: Linux certainly supports SCSI TCQ (and the SATA equivalent, NCQ). However, only unordered tags are supported, not ordered. Other than that, I don't know the answer, and can only suggest to look at how other drivers do it. Also, you might want to try a newer kernel, there has been some changes particularly how cache flushes are implemented since late 2010 or thereabouts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I admit i din't look into simple tagging, only untagged and ordered tagged.  And yeah, looking at other drivers is what we are doing now.

Comment: Did you fix the problem with simple tagging ?

Comment: Problem solved by using fio instead of iometer in linux.  Iometer seemz to be having problem with async io.